# How to adjust the size of the columns of SQLITE select statements results displayed in terminal?

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

Im using Cygwin for windows, and when I send a SELECT statement to the sqlite program, all the column delimiters (the character "`|`") comes right after the values, not forming a fixed column width a( "grid style") result.

I've already tried the `.width` command, but it didn't worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
"I've already tried the .width command, but it didn't worked at all."
```

Did you use `.width NUM1 NUM2 ...` after setting `.mode columns`?